# Cubic Equation Finding Roots

Tags: cubics

How to prove that a particular cubic equation has three real and distinct roots without finding its discriminant via calculus method?

<sup>Please do not use mathematical concepts beyond high school/IIT-JEE.</sup>
Well and if someone is using the method of finding stationary points please explain the logic behind the technique.

Comment: What is the particular cubic equation? If you want to solve one generally you can use Cardano's formula, although it isn't pleasant.

Comment: Find the stationery points? I think one turning point would be above the $x$ axis and one below.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem often works.

Comment: Draw a careful graph in the $x-y$ plane, on graph paper. Actual paper.

Comment: @Sanchayan Consider coming over [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-and-random-talk). You might be interested since there are Indian students out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you know derivatives.

Given $y(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, find the derivative $ y'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$.

To find stationary points you have to solve the equation:
$$
3ax^2+2bx+c=0
$$
that is second degree. So: if this equation has no real roots then the cubic has only one real root. If you find two real solutions $x_1,x_2$ then:

if $ y(x_1)y(x_2) <0$ the cubic has three distinct real roots,

if $ y(x_1)y(x_2) =0$ the cubic has two distinct real roots, one of them double, or three coincident real roots.

if $ y(x_1)y(x_2) >0$ the cubic has only one real root.

Comment: The first option should be y(x1)(x2)<0 right?(for 3 distinct real roots)Thanks a lot.I understood the technique but can someone explain me the concept behind the technique please?What are stationary points?

Comment: Yes! I correct the typo. And added a more exact solution.

Comment: Stationary points are points of local maximum or minimum of the function or point of horizontal flexion of his graph.

Comment: Got it.This helped.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1nG9i_eAjM

Comment: Thank's to Youtube!!! Have you understood ? Don't forget to accept if you are  satisfied :)